# Delete gridview row when datasource is the result from a join statement

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Since the datasource in question is the result of a join statement I have to specify the delete command. I tried to do the following but it's not working.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" DeleteMethod="GridView1_RowDeleting" SelectMethod="GetSubjectPrerequisites" TypeName="EnrolSystemCore.SubjectPrerequisitesDSTableAdapters.subjectsTableAdapter">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="32113" Name="subjectid" QueryStringField="subjectid" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="sj_id" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sj_id" HeaderText="sj_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="sj_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sj_name" HeaderText="sj_name" SortExpression="sj_name" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and created within the .cs file the following method to delete a row:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        int subjectID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["subjectID"]);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        int prerequisite1 = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());

        try
        {
            SubjectPrerequisites subjectPrerequisite1 = new SubjectPrerequisites();
            subjectPrerequisite1.removePreRequisite(subjectID, prerequisite1);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

But whenever i try to delete a row it gives me the following error:

**ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'GridView1_RowDeleting' that has parameters: original_sj_id.**

How should I solve this? I researched on existing solutions but they perform the delete procedure within the aspx page which i don't want.

Comment: `OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"` should be placed on GridView control unless I'm missing something. There is no event `OnRowDeleting` for `ObjectDataSource`

Comment: Yeah it's just the result of trying out multiple things actually, I'm more confident using the mvc framework. I just changed it to `deletemethod` but the error it returns is the same.

Comment: `deletemethod` should come from the same class as `selectmethod` an the parameter is of the same type as `selectmethod` return type.

Comment: The `selectmethod` is specified in the business logic project and has the following signature: `getSubjectPrerequisites(int subjectid)` Since `GridViewDeleteEventArgs e` is then not passed, how would i know which row the user has clicked the delete button on?

Comment: Even when I add a method with the signature `public bool removePreRequisite(int subjectid)` within the class where the selectmethod is specified, it still says: could not find a non-generic method 'removePreRequisite' that has parameters: sj_id.

Comment: change the parameter name to `sj_id`